# 'This' or 'this' at the start?

Tags: sentence-construction, quotation-marks

I want to use 'this' at the start of my sentence. I mean the word this is in single quotation marks, but I'm not sure about the starting letter! Should I write 'This' or 'this'?

1. 'This' is used to introduce people.
2. 'this' is used to introduce people.

Should I go with 1 or 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capitalise the first letter of a sentence, even when it is in a quote, and even if your quote starts in the middle of a sentence of the source.

You can usually rephrase to avoid starting with a quote:

> We use 'this' to introduce people.